# Windows 7 Ultimate: necessary to get Dvorak keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, dvorak

In looking at the [edition comparison for Windows 7](http://store.microsoft.com/Windows7/Compare), ultimate shows that you can switch languages.  That's usually the same thing as switching keyboard layouts as when switching to Dvorak.  Can anyone confirm that one must have ultimate in order to make this switch, or can it be done on any edition?

Comment: I think it's the actual UI language that you can switch (for example, Control Panel can be called Pannello di controllo or whatever)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's available in all versions, just like XP Home and Pro both had it.

Answer (score 2):

Switching languages and switching keyboard layouts are completely different operations.

However be warned that Windows does have the feature/annoyance that it sets the keyboard layout per application.

So, if you have five different keyboard layouts, you can assign applications a layout independently.  Unless you use layouts frequently, you'll see no reason for this.

You can ameliorate the situation by setting the default layout to what you choose or simply use only one layout.

Answer (score 0):

Since it doesn't alter your Windows Language I think it's safe to assume you can use the Dvorak keyboard layout in any version of Windows 7

Edit: tried looking for a source confirming it, but turns out it's not that easy. Just believe me and JohnT!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, I have Windows 7 Ultimate.  I'm sure that at the very least, you can download software to fix it.  It's really easy in 7 Ultimate, though.

Answer (score 0):

I am a DVORAK typist.  And there is the usual keyboard switch to go to DVORAK from QWERTY...BUT!!!!!!  It is extremely faulty.  The language will revert to qwerty with annoying frequency... ie...just about everytime you open a new window, and often just when changing focus to an already open window.  AWFUL